# Latest cordova IBM MFP Plugin(8.0.2023071003) dependency on cordova android

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was building a sample cordova app with
target android sdk 33, cordova-android 12, cordova camera plugin 7.0.0 And while trying to add latest IBM MFP plugin cordova-plugin-mfp v8.0.2023071003, it throws error

> cordova-android version requirement >=6.1 and <12.

However Apache's new camera plugin is in accordance with Android 13 granular permissions and this camera plugin would need the cordova-android version to be 12.0.1

How to overcome this conflict of cordova-android version between cordova-plugin-camera  and cordova-plugin-mfp? I need to support my app users on Android 13 with camera.

Comment: There's no direct solution to resolve this conflict within the Cordova framework. The cordova-plugin-camera requires cordova-android version 12.0.1 or higher to fully support Android 13's granular permissions, while cordova-plugin-mfp requires cordova-android version to be between 6.1 and 12. 

You can do one work around, keep using the stable version of camera and integrate new code or library for camera native side of the code to support android 13 and above.